# Best method to clean up database table orphaned data in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, database

Currently my files and images table has over 100k entries, but I know for a fact that alot of them are orphaned and the files do not exist anymore. What is a best method to cross-reference this data to see if the file exist so i can delete them?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a script I use on my own Drupal sites, you can see if it works for yours, it deletes files and records in the file_managed table that have no references in the Drupal file_usage table, or things that are no longer being used by the Drupal installation.

```
$result = db_query('SELECT fm.fid, fm.uri FROM {file_managed} fm LEFT JOIN {file_usage} fu ON fm.fid = fu.fid WHERE fu.fid IS NULL ORDER BY fm.fid');
$num_files_deleted = 0;
$num_records_deleted = 0;
$time_before_start = time();

foreach ($result as $record) {
    $file = file_load($record -> fid);

    if ($file != FALSE) {
        if (file_delete($file)) {
            print(drupal_realpath($record -> uri) . " has been successfully deleted.\n");
            $num_files_deleted++;
        }
    }

    db_delete('file_managed') -> condition('fid', $record -> fid) -> execute();
    $num_records_deleted++;
}

$time_after_finish = time();
$total_time = ($time_after_finish - $time_before_start);
$total_time_h = $total_time / 3600 % 24;
$total_time_m = $total_time / 60 % 60;
$total_time_s = $total_time % 60;

if ($num_records_deleted || $num_files_deleted >= 1) {
    print("\n\n");
    print($num_files_deleted . " files purged and " . $num_records_deleted . " in " . $total_time_h . ":" . $total_time_m . ":" . $total_time_s . ".\n");
}
else {
    print("Nothing to purge.\n");
}
```

You can try running that on a dev to see if that's also something you would want.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way would be to code something that loops over all files in the database, checks for the physical file's existence, and deletes the record if it doesn't.

It would be a good idea to break this up into a batch job if you have a lot of records, but the basic code would be something like

```
$files = db_query('SELECT fid, uri FROM {file_managed}')->fetchAllKeyed();
foreach ($files as $fid => $uri) {
  if (!file_exists($uri)) {
    file_delete(file_load($fid), TRUE);

    // file_delete() will fail to clear up the records as it doesn't delete the 
    // physical file...
    db_delete('file_managed')->condition('fid', $fid)->execute();
    db_delete('file_usage')->condition('fid', $fid)->execute();
  }
}
```

If you end up using that code make sure you run it on a backed up dev copy first, just to make sure it does exactly what you want.

Comment: `file_delete()` handles that for you...but actually there's a different problem, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You were right, neither file table will get cleared up if the file isn't physically deleted. Good shout, thanks